# How to develop a multi-column drop-down for admin/backend form

Tags: admin, attributes, adminhtml, adminform

In the process of creating a basic extension. I have a field in my backend form that is dynamically linked to all the SKUs in the catalog. When an admin clicks on it, they can select the SKU they would like to use for our purposes. The code is as followed:

```
$products = array();
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSort('sku', 'asc');
$i = 1;
$items = $productCollection->getData();
foreach($items as $item) {
$products[$i]['value'] = $item['sku'];
$products[$i]['label'] = $item['sku'];
$i++;
}

        $fieldset->addField('sku', 'select', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('bannerslider')->__('SKU'),
      'class'     => 'required-entry',
      'required'  => true,
      'values'    => $products,
      'name'      => 'sku',
  ));
```

I'm thinking I could just include more *addAttribute* entries to include as many columns from the catalog listings as necessary but I'm sure there is more to it than that.

The end result is a dropdown that is sorted by SKU but shows other row data in a helpful manner that makes the SKU easier to narrow down and allows the admin to select the SKU intelligently. How much I achieve this? Thanks.

A visual example of what I'm referring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762395/ms-access-display-two-columns-in-combo-box